# Call VBA AddIn macro from VSTO PowerPoint Ribbon

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I've been stuck for a few hours on this problem :

I am developing a PowerPoint AddIn in C# and I want to use a macro from another AddIn which is a PPAM file. The PPAM file is installed and enabled.

In the Application reference I found that I need to use the [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._application.run%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method but I cannot get it working (*nothing happens*)... Here is my code:

```cs
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run("PPspliT.ppam!PPspliT.PPspliT_main", null);
```

`PPspliT.ppam` is the installed AddIn (*which is located here : `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\PPspliT\`*)

The module in which the `PPspliT_main` macro is called is named `PPspliT`.

Another thing I find strange is that Run needs to take two arguments even if the macro doesn't have any argument (*that's why I put null as second argument*).

I also tried to install the AddIn programmatically using this :

```cs
String addinPath = @"C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\PPspliT";
var macroFilePath = Path.Combine(addinPath, "PPspliT.ppam");
var addins = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns.Add(macroFilePath);
if (!(addins.Registered == MsoTriState.msoTrue && addins.Loaded == MsoTriState.msoTrue))
{
  addins.Registered = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
  addins.Loaded = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
}
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
string macroToInvoke = string.Format("{0}!{1}", "PPspliT.ppam", "PPspliT.PPspliT_main");
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run(macroToInvoke, null);
```

Thanks for your help!
Acacio

Comment: "Another thing I find strange is that Run needs to take two arguments even if the macro doesn't have any argument (that's why I put null as second argument)."  Run doesn't require it; it may be a peculiarity of the way .NET interfaces with COM/VBA that you're required by VB.NET to fill in all parameters, optional or not.

Comment: do you see any error at application.Run?

Comment: No there is no error at all but nothing happens. I tried to directly call the routine : Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run("PPspliT_main", null); but still nothing. In fact if you know another way to use this VBA code within my C# project It would be ok since I have the code of the PPspliT add-in and it's pptm file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing was driving me crazy but I found how to get it working ! Here is what I did (using this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306682 :

So as I explained in my question I first programmatically register and load the add-in then I do the following :

```
    private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
    {
       oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
       null, oApp, oRunArgs);
    }

Globals.ThisAddIn.RunMacro(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application , new object[] {"PPspliT_main"});
```

Thanks to everyone for your help !

Comment: Glad you found the answer, and thanks for posting it back.  My.  All that to replace a couple lines of VBA/VB6.  ;-)

Comment: I still don't understand why reflection should be explicitly used and why the Application.Run() approach doesn't work I guess it has to do with how .net wraps around VB.net.. I am new to all this and it's sometimes frustrating to see how things get complicated when using C# and how some features are provided for Excel and aren't for PowerPoint for example...

Answer (score 0):

You should try opening the presentation-enabled macro (PPAM) before requesting it to run (via [`Application.Presentations.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.presentations.open.aspx)). The [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._application.run%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for `Application.Run` states that the presentation must be loaded (*interpreted to mean previously opened*).

```cs
Presentation ppam = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Open(macroFilePath);
string macroToInvoke = string.Format("{0}!{1}", ppam.Name, "PPspliT.PPspliT_main");
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run(macroToInvoke, null);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work and gives the following error : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
Additional information: Presentations (unknown member) : Invalid request.  You must use Addins.Add to load Addin files // The loaded state of an AddIn is equivalent of having it ticked under Options>AddIns therefore it is normal that one cannot open it as a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just pulled up a bit of code in VB6 that calls a routine in a loaded add-in

Assuming a reference to a running instance of PPT in oPPTApp and a Public subroutine in the loaded add-in:

```
Public Sub BlahBlah()
   MsgBox "Hah!  You found me!"
End Sub
```

This will launch it:

```
oPPTApp.Run "BlahBlah"
```

Note that you don't need to provide the name of the add-in or the name of the module where your subroutine lives.

Again, this is how it works from VB5/6 or other VBA routines.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I tried this : Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run("PPspliT_main", null); and still the same, nothing happens. I have the pptm file of the PPspliT Add-in and it's code, if you are aware of another way to use this VBA code within my C#project it would do it ! Its very strange that this doesn't work as the PPspliT Add-in Ribbon button just calls the PPspliT_main routine and it works in that case...