# How to action an event in Word from another .NET application using VSTO

Tags: .net, vba, vsto, ms-word

I’m working on a project that involves migrating a VBA macro-enabled Word document to a VSTO document-level customization. We have a .NET application which is currently able to action the Word VBA macros using Word Interop.

Below is an example line of code in our .NET application which is used to call a macro, SomeMethod, within the macro-enabled document:

```
Word.Application.Application.Run(MacroName:="MyDoc.Module1.SomeMethod")
```

Is there a way in which  we can replicate this with the VSTO document-level customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you would just call `MyDoc.Module1.SomeMethod` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but this is a duplicate of:
[Call VBA AddIn macro from VSTO PowerPoint Ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261634/call-vba-addin-macro-from-vsto-powerpoint-ribbon)

I can also confirm that I have used this exact code in my application successfully.

```
private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
   oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
   null, oApp, oRunArgs);
}
```

Called like this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.RunMacro(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application , new object[] {"VBA macro name"});
```